# Dropdown menus in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a dropdown menu in twitter bootstrap but it doesn't seem to work.
When i click on the dropdown menu it just shows a dead link in the url bar.
Please help!!

Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#"> Girls</a></li>         
          </ul>

        </li>

    </ul>

</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What link is it showing? What do you expect it to do? None of your navbar items have links they all go to # which means "stay on this page"

Comment: I dont want any of my links to leave the page. I just want the dropdown item to display the dropdown menu when i click on it.

Comment: Essentially you've said "this code doesn't do what I want" but you haven't explained what you want it to do.

Comment: I want it to display a navigation bar. And one of the options among them must be a dropdown button. When i click on it it should display a dropdown menu. The kind of which you find when you click the notifications option on facebook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of the bootstrap components require jQuery to function properly. Your page isn't loading jQuery. Add:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Right above where you load `bootstrap.min.js` and you should be good to go

Comment: Thanks!! it worked. The fix was to add jquery above all bootstrap links.